# Request for working configurations of openresty + mobdebug + EmmyLua remote debugging in PHPStorm

Tags: docker, lua, phpstorm, remote-debugging

I'm out of my wits. I'm trying to set up remote debugging of lua code in dockerized openresty. I use PHPStorm with EmmyLua extension, and the mobdebug library on the Lua end. I have been reading and hearing reports of this working for people, but for me stopping on a breakpoint (or immediately after `mobdebug.start()`) works about 15% of the time (evidence that I am **not** completely misconfiguring the thing), including exactly 0% of those places in my code that I actually want to debug.

I will not be debugging this issue. I intend to work around it by using an exact setup that is known to work, so I need someone for whom it does work to tell me what their setup is:

- OS version
- openresty version
- mobdebug version
- any custom patches or hacks you might have applied to get the debugging working
- luasocket version (probably relevant)
- PHPStorm version
- EmmyLua version
- docker and docker-compose version, if applicable
- whatever you may suspect to be relevant

I am willing to completely raze my development environment and rebuild it exactly to the working spec, just to have working Lua debugging.

EDIT: for those interested, here are my detailed symptoms:

- I **can't** stop at actual breakpoints, ever (i.e. after I initially stop after `mobdebug.start()` and then "Resume program" and a line with a breakpoint is hit, but it doesn't stop there)
- I **can** stop after `mobdebug.start()` in code executed from `init_by_lua_block`, i.e. once per server start / config reload
- I **can't** stop after `mobdebug.start()` in any code executed during handling a request, i.e. `ssl_certificate_by_lua_block`, `rewrite_by_lua_block` etc. This is probably understandable because coroutines are involved
- All my attempts at enabling coroutine debugging in request handling code either error out or have no effect:

  - `mobdebug.coro()` in `init_worker_by_lua_block()` errors out with "API disabled in current context" somewhere in `mobdebug.lua`
  - `mobdebug.on()` in the function I want to debug either has no effect, or errors out with "attempt to yield across C-call boundary"; I haven't discerned the pattern yet.

Answer (score 0):

> stopping on a breakpoint (or immediately after mobdebug.start()) works about 15% of the time

Stopping after `mobdebug.start()` should work under all circumstances, except when there is a connection already established to the same debugger controller, so the fact that it doesn't usually points to the system that tries to establish multiple debugging sessions to the same controller/IDE (or no connection can be established at all).

Similarly, there are several reasons why breakpoints may not be working, but if they work in a file as part of a specific setup, then I'd expect them to always work in that case. Some of the reasons why breakpoints may not be working are listed in the documentation: https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-faq#why-breakpoints-are-not-triggered.

mobdebug provides a command line-based controller, so for troubleshooting purposes it may be easier to use that instead of a more complex setup.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly a "should work but doesn't" situation, which is why I want to circumvent the issue by _removing_ my situation and replacing it with one that is known to work - and I am asking people for details of their working setups. This question is not about debugging my situation. I've been trying that for 3 days, and I cannot afford to invest any more time in this approach. My current setup is slated for demolition.

Comment: PLEASE, I implore you! Do YOU have a working setup where you are capable of inserting `mobdebug.start()` in your code and set breakpoints in the IDE, and the IDE (whichever one you use) actually does **reliably** stop on those breakpoints? If you do, PLEASE, I BEG YOU, share your specs because I want to copy them. I would even be willing to switch to Windows for this if that's what it takes. My productivity is CRIPPLED by inability to debug Lua code.

Comment: I described my working setup here: http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/debugging-openresty-nginx-lua-scripts-with-zerobrane-studio, although it's possible that something has changed in openresty that affected that functionality. I'd try a similar setup first, as it was working for me for debugging per-request executions.

Comment: Yes, that's basically my setup. I actually clone ZBS into an intermediate image, copy its lualibs and clibs into the final image, and adjust path and cpath so those are picked up.

I also just ran the CLI controller *in the same container* as openresty, and the symptoms are the same: it stops on `.start()` in init context (and can even stop on breakpoints set with `setb`, the equivalent of which EmmyLua in PHPStorm can't do), but it just won't stop in request context, ever, with all combinations of `.coro()` and `.on()` tried.

I'm using openresty `FROM openresty/openresty:bionic`.